# ASP.Net session not updated in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

when my button is clicked I fire the javascript to get the session..
But value of session not updated...

```
alert('<%= Session["file"]%>');
```

Comment: on click of button, what are you doing? just displaying the value in the session or going server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be up to date if its changed after the page is rendered.

You might want to look at page methods (an ajax system) or another ajax approach.

Answer (score 0):

Any inline code once rendered to the page will not change, which is a normal behavior.
use a Hidden field instead.

mark-up:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["file"] = "Data Here";
    HiddenField1.Value = Session["file"].ToString();
}
```

javascript:

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value);
```